# Why aren't my consumers consuming?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

**EDIT:  I have tracked down the problem to be the part of my program where I download the Zip file and parse it. If I comment that out and replace it with a default line, it parses 10,000 times with no problem.**

Not sure how much of this question should be edited to reflect that finding.

I've written a python program which downloads a zip file which contains a single log file of about 10,000 lines.  It then parses this file, line by line, and puts the data into a database.

Eventually my script will run through 200 servers/zip files and process about 100,000 lines. (Not all servers have the needed file)

However, currently when I run the script with 1 consumer, I only get about 13 lines processed into the database. If I run 2 consumers, I get 24. If I run 10 consumers I get 100, and if I run 20 consumers I get 240.

Sometimes, the result of running the script is "Consumer Finished" with said number of entries in the database (far short of the 10K-30K I'm expecting) But other times, I get an error message:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 262, in _feed
>     send(obj) IOError: [Errno 232] The pipe is being closed
```

What can be causing this problem?  Attached is a modified version of my code to remove sensitive data:

```
import urllib, urlparse
import sys
import os
import datetime
from calculon import Calculon
import random
import pprint
import time
import random
import urllib, urlparse
import traceback
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
from datetime import date, datetime, time, timedelta
import os.path
import requests
import io
import urllib2, cStringIO, zipfile
import re
import httplib
import urlparse

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
  for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
    yield start_date + timedelta(n)



def producer(args):
  print "Producing!"
  logdt_start = args["logdt_start"]
  logdt_end = args["logdt_end"]
  for single_date in daterange(logdt_start, logdt_end):
    logdt = single_date + timedelta(days=1)
    print "Reading log file..."
    for x in range(1,2):
      servername = "server-{0}".format("%02d" % (x,))
      filename = "zipped_log.log{0}".format(logdt.date().isoformat())
      url = "http://url.to.zip.file/{0}/{1}".format(servername, filename)
      zip_path = 'path/to/file/within/zip/{0}/{1}'.format(servername, filename)
      if httpExists(url):
        try:
           request = urllib2.urlopen(url)
           zipinmemory =  cStringIO.StringIO(request.read())
             with zipfile.ZipFile(zipinmemory) as archive:
               with archive.open(zip_path) as log:
                 print "File Found! Reading %s..." % filename
                 for line in log:
                  args["_queue"].put(line)

          print "Queue has approximatly {0} items".format(args["_queue"].qsize())

        except:
          print "exception could not load %s" % url
          traceback.print_exc()
    return True


def httpExists(url):
    host, path = urlparse.urlsplit(url)[1:3]
    found = 0
    try:
        connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)  ## Make HTTPConnection Object
        connection.request("HEAD", path)
        responseOb = connection.getresponse()      ## Grab HTTPResponse Object

        if responseOb.status == 200:
            found = 1
        #else:
            #print "Status %d %s : %s" % (responseOb.status, responseOb.reason, url)
    except Exception, e:
        print e.__class__,  e, url
    return found


def parse_log(line):
    if len(line) < 10 or line[0] != '[':
        return {}
    mod_line = line
    mod_line = mod_line.replace('  ', ' ') #whats this for?
    query_dict = {}
    match = re.search('([\d:\/\s]+)\sUTC', mod_line)
    s = match.start()
    e = match.end() - 5
    query_dict['date_ts'] = datetime.strptime(mod_line[s:e], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f')
    e = e+2
    mod_line = mod_line[e:]
    match = re.search('(\w+)\sLogger:\s', mod_line)
    e = match.end()
    query_dict['status'] = match.group(1)
    mod_line = mod_line[e:]
    for key_value in re.split(',', mod_line):
        keypair = re.search('(\w+)=(\w+)', key_value)
        key = keypair.group(1)
        value = keypair.group(2)
        query_dict[key] = value
    return query_dict

def consumer(args):
  global consumed
  consumed += 1
  print "Consumed : {0}".format(consumed)
  try:
    db = args["db"]
    cname = args["cname"]
    arg_value = args["_value"]

    cur = db.cursor()
    error_count = 0


    if arg_value is None:
        print "Consumer Finished!"
        return False
    line = arg_value
    qdict = parse_log(line)

    if len(qdict) == 0:
        print "No data to consumer %s" % cname
        return None

    query = """
    INSERT INTO my_db(date_ts,
        status, cmd, creativeString, environment_id, client_type_id, platform_id, sn_type_id, user_id,
        device_id, invoker_sn_id, invoker_type, poster_sn_id, origin, event_type, creative_id, ch,
         src, afp, cmp, p1, p2,p3)
    VALUES (%(date_ts)s,%(status)s,%(cmd)s,%(creativeString)s,%(environment_id)s,%(client_type_id)s,%(platform_id)s,
    %(sn_type_id)s,%(user_id)s,%(device_id)s,%(invoker_sn_id)s,%(invoker_type)s,%(poster_sn_id)s,%(origin)s,
    %(event_type)s,%(creative_id)s,%(ch)s, %(src)s, %(afp)s, %(cmp)s,
    %(p1)s, %(p2)s, %(p3)s);
    """

    try:
      cur.execute(cur.mogrify(query, qdict))
      db.commit()
      global processed
      processed += 1
      print "processed : {0}".format(processed)
    except:
      error_count = error_count + 1
      print "ERROR in insert {0}".format(error_count)
      traceback.print_exc()
      print qdict
      sys.exit(2)   
  except:
      print "Error in parsing:  "  + val
      tracback.print_exc()
      sys.exit(12)

def main():
  log_start = datetime(2015,1,19);
  log_end = datetime(2015,1,20);
  consumer_args_list = []

  noOfConsumers = 1;
  for x in range(0, noOfConsumers):
    print "Creating Consumer {0}".format(x)
    print "Connecting to logs db..."
    db_name = 'mydb'
    connString = "dbname={0} host={1} port={2} user={3} password={4}".format(db_name, 'localhost', 5433, 'postgres',                                                                       'pword')
    db = psycopg2.connect(connString)
    consumer_args = {"cname": "CONSUMER_{0}".format(x), "db":db}
    consumer_args_list.append(consumer_args)

  calculon = Calculon( producer, 
        [{"logdt_start": log_start,
          "logdt_end": log_end}],
            True,
            consumer,
            consumer_args_list,
            True)
  result = calculon.start()

consumed = 0
processed = 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The output looks like this:

```
> Creating Consumer 0
Connecting to logs db...
Producing!
Reading log file...
File Found! Reading log2015-01-20...
Queue has approximatly 9549 items
Consumed : 1
processed : 1
Consumed : 2
processed : 2
Consumed : 3
processed : 3
Consumed : 4
processed : 4
Consumed : 5
processed : 5
Consumed : 6
processed : 6
Consumed : 7
processed : 7
Consumed : 8
processed : 8
Consumed : 9
processed : 9
Consumed : 10
processed : 10
Consumed : 11
processed : 11
Consumed : 12
processed : 12
Consumed : 13
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 262, in _feed
    send(obj)
IOError: [Errno 232] The pipe is being closed
```

Comment: Sounds silly but maybe just single threading makes sense for this? Or is it much too slow.

Comment: @ZachLeighton Much too slow.

Comment: I do not know how Calculon works. Some clues after a quick look : the error is on the send side, it looks like your consumers die after a time. Could it be possible that when the queue is empty, (because producer is waiting for ...) a consumer decides it has finished its job and exits instead of waiting for more input ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta The only problem is that the queu says it has 9,549  items in it still.  But assuming that is printing in a race condition out of order, any ideas on how  I could keep the queue full?

Comment: @Avik : it was just a wild guess, and visibly not a good one  :-( . You could anyway control in producer that the queue never was empty all along processing.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I've narrowed down the problem to be related to how I read the zip file.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error turned out to be a bad line in the input file, which broke the regular expression.

For example:  One of the values of the comma seperated list was: `foobar=2, foo=Something here, is ,a really, poor value, bar=2`

I was able to fix the problem by adding the following code within the consumer method:

```
    try:
      qdict = parse_adx_client_log(line)
    except:
      qdict = {}
      print "BAD LINE {0}".format(line)

    if len(qdict) == 0:
       print "No data to consumer %s" % cname
       return None
```